# How can I get a package manager on a Samsung Chromebook?

Tags: package-management, gentoo, chrome-os, chrome-book

I have enabled developer mode, and I can access the shell, but I don't have the emerge command, I remember reading that ChromeOS is built on Gentoo.

How can I get a package manager on ChromeOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered the `dev_install` command, it sets up `emerge`, the Gentoo package manager.

Comment: Are you able to install most Gentoo packages using this? I'm interested in installing custom Unix packages on Chrome OS as well.

Comment: No, it was frustratingly limited.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I guess crouton + a full Ubuntu install is the way to go then!